# How to delete a collection (one to many relation) in Propel?

Tags: propel

I have one to many relationship model on my database. For example, one property has more than one price:

```
property 1 => $200, $300  
property 2 => $200, $350  
etc.
```

This how to create property :

```
$prices = array();
$property = new Property();
$property->setName('property 3');

$data_prices = array(200,300,400);
foreach ($data_prices as $price {
   $prc = new Price();
   $prc->setPrice($price);
   $prices[] = $prc; #object collection
}
$property->setPrices($prices);
$property->save();
#codes above create new records on table property and prices (related) and property id = 1
```

But when I try to update :

```
$prices = array();
$property = PropertyQuery::create()->findOneByPropertyId(1);
#create new prices
$data_prices = array(10,20,30);
    foreach ($data_prices as $price) {
       $prc = new Price();
       $prc->setPrice($price);
       $prices[] = $prc; #object collection
    }
$property->setPrices($prices);
$property->save();
```

instead of deleting old price records or updating them, Propel creates new records. I want to delete old price records because I don't need them, or, if I can update the old with the new price it would be great.

How to do this in Propel?

Comment: How are you relating each price to the property? Or do you just have the Price as a single column table?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the Price objects as new does just that—creates new Price objects. You need to either call the Price objects from the Property object or load the Price objects inside your foreach loop. Since I don't know the structure of your Price table, I can only give you the former solution:

```
$prices = array();
$property = PropertyQuery::create()->findOneByPropertyId(1);
$prices = $property->getPrices();
$data_prices = array(10,20,30);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data_prices); $i++) {
    if (!isset($prices[$i])) {
        $prc = new Price();
        $prc->setPrice($price);
        $prc->save();
        $prices[] = $prc;
    } else {
        $prc = $prices[$i];
        $prc->setPrice($data_prices[$i]);
        $prc->save();
    }
}
$property->save();
```